# How to curve a cube mesh around a circle perimeter

Tags: modifiers

I have a simple cube mesh that I want to modify so it will wrap around my circle's perimeter by 90 degrees like I have drawn here acting like a curved wall piece:

[image]

I looked in modifiers and tried Curve modifier but was not sure how to use it, does any one know how to do it ?

Comment: if you want it to wrap around I guess you need to scale it on an axis, subdivide it so that it can bend, and use a Curve modifier. You can also use the Simple Deform modifier set to Bend mode

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **"spin tool"**.

Start with a plane section.

Place the 3d cursor at the center of the circle.

Use the spin tool which will be placed at the 3D cursor location (thanks for the information, Robin). By default, the tool will rotate around the Z axis.

[image]

Once the operation validated you can tune the values, such as the number of extrusions and the angle.

Comment: If I'm not wrong.. (I suppose you'd better check, too) the spin tool _always_ uses the cursor as pivot? It's the orientation that matters.

Comment: @RobinBetts, you're right. Never noticed it before (of course), will edit this. Thanks.